# Unknown type error in .mm file

Tags: objective-c++

I have a .mm file called A.mm, and in it I import B.hpp file, I use the struct C in B.hpp.

But the Xcode build will report unknown type error, it demands me to add the namespace before the C class.

If I click go to definition of C class it can jump to the right place in B.hpp. So I wonder can I do something to avoid adding long namespace prefix?

Comment: I‘m not sure what you are asking? Do you mean you can‘t use a ‚using‘statement?

Comment: using namespace works! Thanks you. I am sorry I am new to objective-c C++